# Study of a function

Tags: functions, derivatives

I have to find the relative maximum and minimum points of this function $y=|x^2-4x|$ distinguishing stationary points from angular points.
I tried to see this function as $y=x^2-4x$ as $x>0$ and $y=-x^2+4x$ as $x<0$ then I derived and then $y'>0$
but It is wrong because I find only one point which is $x=2$..
Can someone help me in a clear way please?
Thanks for your help I'm completely stuck...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you notice that the followings are parabolas?
$$y=x^2-4x=(x-2)^2-4$$
$$y=-x^2+4x=-(x-2)^2+4$$

Comment: sorry but it does not help me, I can't figure out the hint, I'm not sure if my interpretation of the function is correct..

Comment: @Dipok All parabolas only have one extrema, and it can be immediately read off from the forms given in this answer.  You do not need calculus to solve this problem.  (that's the hint)

Comment: PERFECT, I drew the function and immediately figure out that the max is for x=2 and the two minimum are for x=0 and x=4 precising that x=2 is a stationary point :-)

Comment: I have only one doubt now, Is it correct to divide the initial function into two parts as I have done?

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is considering only the cases $x<0$ and $x\ge0$; but the expression $x^2-4x$ changes from positive to negative also at $x=4$. So you have to divide the study into two cases:

1. If $x<0$ or $x>4$, then $f(x)=x^2-4x$;
2. If $0\le x\le 4$, then $f(x)=4x-x^2$.

The derivative of $f$ is thus
$$
f'(x)=
\begin{cases}
2x-4 & \text{if $x<0$ or $x>4$},\\
4-2x & \text{if $0<x<4$},
\end{cases}
$$
and the function is not differentiable at $0$ and $4$.

The only critical point is where the derivative is zero, that is, $x=2$. Since $f'(x)=4-2x$ is positive in a left neighborhood of $2$ (excluding $2$) and negative in a right neighborhood, you know that this is a point of maximum. Instead $0$ and $4$ are points of minimum, because $f(0)=f(4)=0$ and, obviously, $f(x)\ge0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: My doubt was indeed about the point 4 now it's all clear ;-)

Answer (score 1):

here taking derivatives wont help you because your function is not differentiable at two points. try this
given $$y>=0$$
 ie a minimum occurs at $$y=0$$
ie $$x(x-4)=0$$
therefore $2$ minima occurs at $$x=0,x=4$$